# debugbar and sweetalert plugins incompatibility issue

Tags: octobercms, sweetalert, phpdebugbar

In an OctoberCMS app, i have both debugbar and Swal Sweetalert plugins installed.

With sweetalert plugin activated, when i use this line in my code

```
debugbar::info('something');
```

The message is displayed one second and disappears. Obviously like that, it is less easy to use debug feature.

So in my dev environment, i have to uninstall sweet alert plugin to be able to debug with debugbar

Have you some tips to fix it without uninstall swal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the plugin's author answer

> Swal plugin make some ajax request to load the latest Flash messages.
>   Using Debugbar, you need to select another top request, from right
>   dropdown. And them you can see the log.

[image]